# Preventing overwriting when using numpy.savetxt

Tags: numpy

Is there built error handling for prevent overwriting a file when using numpy.savetxt? 
If 'my_file' already exists, and I run

numpy.savetxt("my_file", my_array)

I want an error to be generated telling me the file already exists, or asking if the user is sure they want to write to the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check if the file already exists before you write your data:

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('my_file'): numpy.savetxt('my_file', my_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass instead of a filename a file handle to `np.savetxt()`, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10)
with open("/tmp/tst.txt", 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,a)
```

So you could write a helper for opening the file.

Answer (score 1):

Not in Numpy. I suggest writing to a `namedTemporaryFile` and checking if the destination file exists. If not, rename the file to a concrete file on the system. Else, raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not an error handler, but it's possible to create a new version in the form of:

```
file  
filev2  
filev2v3  
filev2v3v4
```

so that no file ever gets overwritten.

```
n=2
while os.path.exists(f'{file}.txt'):
    file = file + f'v{n}' 
    n+=1
```